Reaction between sodium hydroxide and glass?
In terms of storage, I thought that glass was the safest bet for chemicals: No leeching, no real degradation (neglecting it's an amorphous solid), affordable, etc...
However, I recently heard that NaOH will actually react with glass. What is this reaction? What is the preferred way to store sodium hydroxide, if not glass?

You might have heard that measuring pH of strongly alkalic solutions by "glass electrode" is not the best idea.

@Poutnik Indeed.

Our lab NaOH solutions - up to the 50% stuff - comes in HDPE screwtop jugs like these https://www.merckmillipore.com/GB/en/product/Sodium-hydroxide-solution-500-0,MDA_CHEM-158793

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32588/why-must-naoh-be-kept-dry-during-storage https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163059/reaction-of-silicon-dioxide-with-sodium-hydroxide https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/156367/reaction-between-sodium-hydroxide-and-silicon-dioxide
